# How to typespec guards in a human friendly way?

Tags: elixir, dialyzer, typespec

### Background

I am playing with guards and I want my guard definitions to also have a typespec:

```
defmodule AuctionHouse.Shared.ExtraGuards do
  @moduledoc """
  Contains additional guards to use in functions.
  """

  defguard is_pos_integer(value) when is_integer(value) and value > 0
end
```

### Problem

So, now that I have this simple guard, I want a spec for it. However, dyalizer's suggestion doesn't strike me as exactly *human readable*.

```
@spec is_pos_integer(any) ::
          {:__block__ | {:., [], [:andalso | :erlang, ...]}, [],
           [{:= | {any, any, any}, list, [...]}, ...]}
defguard is_pos_integer(value) when is_integer(value) and value > 0
```

I believe this is likely defined as a function that takes `any` as an argument but the return type is very difficult for me to understand.  I *assume* it means it creates erlang code, like a macro, but I can't make sense of it.

### Questions

- What does the return type mean?
- Is there a way to make this more human readable? If so, how?

Comment: Any guard has a spec `@spec is_something(any) :: boolean()` by a definition of guard. Could you please elaborate what are you after?

Comment: I want the typesepc for the `defguard is_pos_integer` to be understandable, instead of `:__block__ | {:., [], [:andalso | :erlang, ...]}, [],
           [{:= | {any, any, any}, list, [...]}, ...]}`

Comment: I don't think that return typespec is a boolean :P

Comment: Have you tried `@spec is_pos_integer(any) :: boolean()`
It looks like dialyzer suggested abstract-syntax-tree stuff, which is (like you said) unreadable by humans.

Comment: @Everett dialyzer suggests what it can derive and `defguard/1` is a macro, hence it is expected to return an AST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested spec that you get is like that because it's the spec for the **AST returned by the guard**, since the guard is a macro under the hood. Essentially it means you're passing your guard some *code* (not value), and getting back some other code.

Short answer is that you probably don't want to type this. The correct typespec could be something like:

```elixir
@spec is_pos_integer(Macro.t()) :: Macro.t()
```

which is not very useful. I'd probably go with no spec  We take the same approach in Elixir's standard library itself. For example, [`Integer.is_odd/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#is_odd/1) is a guard very similar to the `is_pos_integer/1` one here, and we have no spec for that.

Comment: Specs for guards add no value to the static analysis. I don't think it should be there either.

Comment: Adding `@doc` then seems to be the way to go here!